# Como usar o "setViewBinder" no meu adapter para Listview

Tags: java, android

Como eu faço para usar o setViewBinder no meu adapter? No SimpleCursorAdapter eu consigo:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.lista_chamados, cursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);


    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){


           public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){

               }
               return false;
           }
        });
```

Porém no meu adapter não consigo. Como devo fazer?

Comment: Qual a classe do seu `Adapter`? Na API, apenas o `SimpleCursorAdapter` e o `SimpleAdapter` aceitam essa interface. No caso do seu `Adapter`, poderia extender `SimpleAdapter` para usar essa interface.

Comment: Qual seria a superclasse dessa classe?

Comment: @Wakim não estou conseguindo extender `SimpleAdapter` para tal. Existe outra maneira de customizar um objeto do listview como faria com o `setViewBinder`?